# Accessing a repeated element in the list and printing the element next to it

Tags: python, list, find-occurrences

I have this function, which takes 3 arguments.
1) a list containing strings, 2) search_term and 3) place (optional argument).

Code:

```
def ls_src(list,search_term,place=1):
    if search_term in list:
        a = list[list.index(search_term)+1]+':' + '\tThe second element of of search term is ' + (search_term[place])
        return a
```

Now I want to access the element next to search_term, but if the element is repeated in the list, it should also consider the other occurrences of that element, and not the first occurrence of the element only.

If `list_search(['a','b','c','a','e'],'a')`
then, the function should return 'b' and 'e' both, as they are the elements next to 'a'.

So my question is, how do we access the other occurrences of 'a', and not just the first occurrence.

Comment: It is ill-advised to use `list` as a variable name in Python.

Comment: I'm just a beginner here. So thanks for the advice. I'll take care of it.

Comment: What is the expected behavior for listsearch(['a','b', 'a'], 'a') ?

Comment: In case of `['a', 'a', 'b']` the expected output when searching `'a'` is `['a','b']` or just `['a']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build the new list using an iterator and the `next()` function.

```
def list_search(input_list, search_term, place=1):
    terms = iter(input_list)
    new_list = []
    try:
        [new_list.append(terms.next()) for term in terms if term == search_term[place-1]]
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return new_list


tests = [
    (['a','b','c','a','e'], 'a', 1),
    (['a','b','c','a','e'], 'b', 1),
    (['a','b','c','a','e'], 'ab', 2),
    (['a','b','c','a','e'], 'e', 1),
    (['a','a','a'], 'b', 1),
    (['a','a','a'], 'a', 1)]

for input_list, search_term, place in tests:
    print list_search(input_list, search_term, place)
```

These tests will give you the following results:

```
['b', 'e']
['c']
['c']
[]
[]
['a']
```

Comment: I tried this code, but the problem is it doesn't run in python3 as there is no function called 'next()' in it, but it worked just fine for python2 .

Comment: I think for Python3 you just need to replace it with `next(terms)`. Not able to test it here at the moment though.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `enumerate` function which helps to get the element along with it's index.

```
def list_search(l, s):
    for i,j in enumerate(l):
        if j == s:
            print(l[i+1])

list_search(['a','b','c','a','e'],'a')
```

**Output:**

```
b
e
```

**or**

There may be a chance of  search element also be present at the last, so put the print statement inside `try` `except` block.

```
def list_search(l, s):
    for i,j in enumerate(l):
        if j == s:
            try:
                print(l[i+1])
            except IndexError:
                pass    

list_search(['a','b','c','a','e', 'a'],'a')
```

Comment: You need to cater for when `a` is the last element in the input list, current code would have index out of range

Comment: I think the function should return list instead of printing, as per OP.

Comment: But is there any simpler way to solve this problem? I mean any other way except using enumerate function.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer code that is more descriptive you could take an approach like this. It's a little longer but you avoid one character variables.

The other aspect this provides is if the query string follows itself, it won't be returned. That can be changed by removing the last `if` test.

```
def search_terms(terms, query):
    found = []
    count = len(terms)
    for index, term in enumerate(terms):
        next_index = index + 1
        if term == query and next_index < count and terms[next_index] != query:
            found.append(terms[next_index])
    return found

print search_terms(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'a'], 'a')
# ['b', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
def search(l,term):

    for num in range(len(l)):

        if l[num]==term:

            print (l[num+1])
```

search(['python','html','python','c++','python','java'], 'python')

**Output:**

```
html

c++

java
```